# Compare first digits of table content only in sql query

Tags: mysql

I have the following `MySQL` query

```
UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE products_id = '8523'
AND customers_id = '7221'
```

but `products_id` is suffixed with `':'` and additional numbers, so for instance it could be

```
8523:d32ee9341c0e1d75b8ab25be583a3829.
```

The additional numbers relate to selected attributes.

Does `MySQL` have the ability to only compare `products_id` against the value BEFORE the colon when it processes the `WHERE` part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something as

```
UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE 
substring_index(products_id,':',1) = '8523'
AND customers_id = '7221'
```

Comment: I went with this answer as it was least likely to cause issues if for instance the customer had product id 8523 AND 8523x in cart.

Answer (score 1):

use "like" operator :

```
UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE products_id LIKE '8523%'  // return all id starting by 8523...
AND customers_id = '7221'
```

"Like" operator :

```
LIKE '%a%' // all which contains 'a'
LIKE 'a%'  // all which starting by 'a' 
LIKE '%a'  // all which ending by 'a'
```

Comment: Plus One for giving the explanation on different usage of LIKE. This will most likely prove useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

try
 `UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE products_id like  '8523:%'
AND customers_id = '7221'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE:

`UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE products_id like '8523:%'
AND customers_id = '7221'`

Explanation of LIKE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use like clause in this case also:

Such as-

```
UPDATE customers_basket
SET flag = '1'
WHERE products_id LIKE '8523%'
AND customers_id = '7221';
```

This may be helpful to you.